# Function to get the determinant of a NxN matrix using laplace expansion in R (Error: argument of length 0)

Tags: r, function, matrix, determinants

```
determinant_laplace <- function(M, k = 1) {
  n <- nrow(M)
  
  det_value <- 0
  sign <- 1
  for (j in 1:n) {
    sub_matrix <- M[-k, -j]
    sub_det <- determinant_laplace(sub_matrix, k = 1)  
    
    det_value <- det_value + sign * M[k, j] * sub_det
    sign <- -sign
  }
  return(det_value)
}
# Example usage
B = matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3)
B
determinant_laplace(B) 
det(B)
```

This is what I have so far. When I run it I get a error," Error in 1:n : argument of length 0". I ran it with debugger on and found that n is NULL but I don't know why or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As pointed out by @Onyambu in the comment, you should be aware that `k=1` can be hard coded within your function (rather than taken as an input argument), since you **always** start the expansion from the **1st** row of matrices during the recursion. That means, we, indeed, are able to simplify the function further.

Below is an example with further simplification

```
determinant_laplace <- function(M) {
  if (length(M) == 1) {
    return(M)
  }
  det_value <- numeric(nrow(M))
  for (j in seq_along(det_value)) {
    det_value[j] <- (-1)^(j - 1) * M[1, j] * Recall(M[-1, -j, drop = FALSE])
  }
  return(sum(det_value))
}
```

---

You are using recursion to compute the matrix determinant and I think you missed two things in your code (see the first two comments and the code below)

```
determinant_laplace <- function(M, k = 1) {
  # add a termination condition to finish the recursion
  if (length(M) == 1) {
    return(M)
  }  
  n <- nrow(M)
  det_value <- 0
  sign <- 1
  for (j in 1:n) {
    # option `drop = FALSE` should be specified, otherwise, 1-by-1 matrix would be collapsed into a scalar, which leads to the error you have seen in your original code
    sub_matrix <- M[-k, -j, drop = FALSE]
    sub_det <- determinant_laplace(sub_matrix, k = 1)
    det_value <- det_value + sign * M[k, j] * sub_det
    sign <- -sign
  }
  return(c(det_value)) # Optional: use `c()` to make a scalar output
}
```

and a simple test we can try

```
> set.seed(1)

> n <- 5

> (B <- matrix(runif(n^2), nrow = n))
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.2655087 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992 0.9347052
[2,] 0.3721239 0.94467527 0.1765568 0.7176185 0.2121425
[3,] 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.6516738
[4,] 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.3800352 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452 0.2672207

> determinant_laplace(B)
[1] -0.05779661

> det(B)
[1] -0.05779661
```

Comment: This is good. but whats the reason for `k`?

Comment: @Onyambu that selects the first row for the computation

Comment: But you can always just use `1` you do not need a parameter. k can only be 1. You cannot use any other value and get the correct determinant. Thus k should not be a parameter. just do `M[-1,-j]`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, that's true. I am not about to change the code much, but just let OP know where the error happened. Your advice should reach OP directly so OP can be aware of it.